Minimizing the average absolute deviation from a constant
Let $c, d, K\in \mathbb{R}$. I am interested in finding $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ that minimizes the integral
\begin{equation}
I = \int_c^d |K - \alpha x| dx
\end{equation}
If it is not possible in general, are there extra conditions or slight variations that make optimization possible? For instance, requiring $K>0$, or perhaps replacing the absolute value for the squared-distance.

Can't you just split the integral into two parts such that $K-\alpha x$ is positive on one part and negative on the other, and then calculate the integral?
